# Configure PSTricks on TeXstudio

Tags: pdftex, pstricks, texstudio

I'm stuck with PSTricks on TeXstudio,

I'm getting errors like

```
auto-pst-pdf: . Or turn off auto-pst-pdf.}
```

1. My current latex version

   ```
   Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2013/dev)
   ```
2. Build and View command is

   ```
   txs:///pdflatex | txs:///pdflatex | txs:///bibtex | txs:///pdflatex | txs:///pdflatex
   ```

Comment: you are using Texlive 2013 developmental version. there is no pre-test version available. So use a stable texlive 2012. of course you can help in testing texlive 2013 once its pre-release is available.

Comment: You should (probably) call pdflatex with the switch `--shell-escape`.

Comment: so, should i modify the command to txs:///pdflatex --shell-escape | txs:///pdflatex --shell-escape| txs:///bibtex | txs:///pdflatex --shell-escape| txs:///pdflatex --shell-escape ??

Comment: nopes, it doesn't work, i've tried this as well, still the same, txs:///pdflatex -enable-write18 | txs:///pdflatex -enable-write18 | txs:///bibtex | txs:///pdflatex -enable-write18 | txs:///pdflatex -enable-write18

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
% !TeX program = xelatex
```

and then do *not* use the package `auto-pst-pdf`